# Can,t return JSP/HTML page using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, controller

I have created a simple controller in Spring MVC app to return a JSP page. But I always get error -> WARNING: No mapping for GET /MVC2/pages/test.jsp .

Tools used : Eclipse 2022-03, Spring 5.3.9, Java 8, Tomcat 9

[Project Structure]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dkcq.png

[Request URL]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHDwl.png

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
  "xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
   <display-name>MVC2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyFrontController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myBeans.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MyFrontController</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <absolute-ordering></absolute-ordering>
   </web-app>
```

myBeans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pi.controller"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven> 

<bean id="resolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

JspController.java

```
package com.pi.controller;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/serverPages")
   public class JspController {

   public JspController() {
    System.out.println("JspController initialzing ...");
   }

   @RequestMapping("/jspPage")
   public String getPage() {
    System.out.println(" getPage() method called.");
    return "test";
  }
  }
```

test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>JSP page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>This is test JSP page.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error

```
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.55
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 10 2021 08:26:45 UTC
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.55.0
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\jre
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_341-b10
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         
G:\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.55
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - 
Dcatalina.base=G:\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.55
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - 
Dwtp.deploy=G:\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.55\endorsed
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path[C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Users/Piyush/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/Piyush/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\Piyush\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Piyush\Desktop;;.]
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1865] milliseconds
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:04 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took             [1,085] milliseconds.
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:05 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'MyFrontController'
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'MyFrontController'
JspController initialzing ...
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 4851 ms
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [8878] milliseconds
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:13 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /MVC2/
 getPage() method called.
Aug 18, 2022 2:29:30 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /MVC2/pages/test.jsp
```